# WP on localhost to wordpress's domain

Tags: wordpress

I have developed my site on localhost (there is lot of customizations, plugins, own theme etc., database, lot of posts etc. ) and now I look for easy way how to uplaod it on wordpress's domain. On my own domain/server it is esay but i do not know how to do it on wordpress's domain. When I want to upload on wordpress domain have i ftp access and some phpadmin or something like this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is double, did you want a WP on wordpress.com or do you want it on your own hosting?

Comment: I HAVE WP on localhost AND i want to have WP on *.wordpress.com

Comment: Try reading the getting started first: http://learn.wordpress.com/get-started/

Comment: Always when I write a question first I research.. i did not find ;( but maybe I will be able to import wp content with my localhost or first I transfer wp to my private server and after that I import to *.wordress.com. But it is not fast solution ;/

Comment: Wordpress has an import/export function that u can use to "copy" your content ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're moving to wordpress.COM, you need to Export your content using Tools>>Export and then import into wordpress.com. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

There is no database import at wordpress.com, and you can't upload your own theme, either.

This is the method for moving to self-hosted wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress And use http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to safely change URLs in the database.