# What is the best strategy to switch from localhost to another environment in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, devops

I have a wordpress which works fine in localhost. Now we need to deploy it on our testing environment using docker. Deploy php files with docker was fine. I configured worpdress to use environment variables instead hardcoded values in wp-config.php.

```
docker run -d --name wordpress -it --rm -p 80:80 \
-e DB_HOST=10.10.10.10:3306 \
-e DB_USER=root \
-e DB_PASSWORD=secret \
-e DB_NAME=wordpress \
-e AUTH_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e SECURE_AUTH_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e NONCE_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e LOGGED_IN_KEY=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e AUTH_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e SECURE_AUTH_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e LOGGED_IN_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e NONCE_SALT=$RANDOM_KEY \
-e WP_DEBUG=true \
-e DISABLE_WP_CRON=true \
-e TZ=America/Lima wordpress:5.7.2
```

The problem is in the database deployment. I exported a dump from my localhost and imported to my new testing database. I saw that in the database dump, all the urls are hardcoded with localhost:

```
table wp_options
'siteurl','http://localhost'

table wp_posts
'you should go to <a href=\"http://localhost/wp-admin/...''

table wp_users
1,'admin','****','admin','admin@mail.com','http://localhost'
```

When I try to access to my testing domain, assets are being downloaded from localhost, ignoring my domain. I understand that this behavior is due to the hardcoded "localhost" in the exported db from developer machine.

[image: errors]

### Research

- [WP on localhost to wordpress's domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018377/wp-on-localhost-to-wordpresss-domain)

  - I which show another way to export the database from localhost.
- [WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-wp_home-constant-contains-a-variable/)

  - I'm not a wordpress/php programmer, so I don't know if these variables can be dangerous.

### Questions

- What is the best strategy to move from localhost to another environment in wordpress for a devops pipeline in which all is handled with **variables** and human intervention is not required?
- Would a simple string replacement (localhost > wordpress.testing.com) in the mysql dump work?

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress domain is controlled by setting 2 database options:

- site_url
- home

If you don't want to change it in database you can do it in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', $_ENV["USER"]);
define('WP_HOME', $_ENV["HOME"]);
```

You can make it read from an environment variable and then set that inside the container.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, however it will not account for media that have been uploaded and attached to content. I would suggest to scrub the database by running `wp search-replace` through [WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) as well, to ensure everything gets cleaned. [Wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove) is also pretty powerful.

Comment: #1 @guerrilla is the same value for both variables?  #2 in localhost should be "http://localhost" and in testing another value?

Comment: @maiorano84 I will try `wp search-replace` with this sentence:  `wp search-replace 'http://localhost' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid`. Do yo have the exact parameters? Thanks!

Comment: that variables work at 99%. There are some links that developer should change manually, directly on the database or admin :(. I think is a wordpress limitation :S